# When provide login method by using new Twitter API Free v2, Can user use same django user ID by using same Twitter ID?

Tags: django-allauth

This is topic related to the announcement Twitter API changes in March 2023.

There is a Django user ID(1) created with django-allauth and the old Twitter API.

If I provide login method by new Twitter API (Free v2), Can the user log on same Django-ID (user ID(1)) by using same Twitter ID?
Or even if the user log in with the same Twitter ID, will that method make a different new Django-userID?

I haven't tried it yet for fear of losing the user's current ID.